# Flutter How to clickable the selected item in bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation

I'm trying to implement clickable the selected item in the Bottom navigation bar in my Flutter app. What I'm trying to achieve is when the user clicks any item in the Bottom navigation bar the selected item page contains the button which navigates to another inner page so if I want to try to click the select item in the Bottom navigation bar it shows me the same inner page, the app changes the selected tab inside the bottom navigation bar. but if I click again the select item tab it shows me the same inner page. Any help is appreciated.

`Or Maybe it's clickable but the selected tab shows me the inner page only`

Any help is appreciated.

My main.dart:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'MyPage.dart';
import 'MyPage2.dart';
import 'MyPage3.dart';
import 'package:double_back_to_close_app/double_back_to_close_app.dart';
import 'Notifications.dart';
import 'MyCustomPage.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

 @override
 _MyAppcreateState() => _MyApp();
}

class _MyApp extends State<MyApp> {
 late List<Widget> _pages;

 List<BottomNavigationBarItem> _items = [
  BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
  label: "Home",
),
BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: Icon(Icons.messenger_rounded),
  label: "Messages",
),
BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
  label: "Settings",
)
];

late int _selectedPage;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_selectedPage = 0;

_pages = [
  MyPage(
    count: 1,
  ),
  MyPage2(
    count: 2,
  ),
  MyPage3(
    count: 3,
  ),
 ];
 }
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  print(_selectedPage);
  return Scaffold(
    body: _pages[_selectedPage],
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    items: _items,
    currentIndex: _selectedPage,
    onTap: (index) {

        setState(() {

          _selectedPage = index;
        });

    },
  )
);
}
}
```

MyPage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'MyCustomPage.dart';
import 'Notifications.dart';

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
 final count;
 MyPage({Key? key, this.count}) : super(key: key);


 @override
 _MyPage createState() => _MyPage();
 }


class _MyPage extends State<MyPage>{

 late int _selectedPage;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Navigator(
  onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('page 01'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text('my page1'),
              onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (ctx) => MyCustomPage()
                  )
                  );

              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
}
}
```

MyCustomPage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyCustomPage extends StatefulWidget {
MyCustomPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_MyCustomPage createState() => _MyCustomPage();
}


class _MyCustomPage extends State<MyCustomPage>{
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext parentContext) {
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('custompage'),
  ),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 15,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Card(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('My Custom Page'),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

I add the image for a better understanding:-

my home page view

[image: my home which contains a button that navigates to the inner page and in the bottom bar the selected item is the home icon]

MycustomPage/inner page view

[image: when I click on the button it shows me the inner page but you see the home icon is still selected and if I click on the selected home icon it shows the same inner page.]

this is my issue what I want is when I navigate to the inner page the select tab must be unselectable and when I click on that selected tab it will show the first page which is MyPage.dart page, not the inner page(MyCustomPage.dart).

Please answer me if any further questions.
Please comment to me if you don't understand it.

But please don't ignore this. I really want to do that task.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Till I understood this thing is not possible with default **BottomNavigationBar**
maybe you can with custom. this is already a predefined index in the BottomNavigationBar constructor and set it to **"0"**

**int currentIndex = 0,**

```
BottomNavigationBar(
{Key? key,
required List<BottomNavigationBarItem> items,
ValueChanged<int>? onTap,
int currentIndex = 0,
double? elevation,
BottomNavigationBarType? type,
Color? fixedColor,
Color? backgroundColor,
double iconSize = 24.0,
Color? selectedItemColor,
Color? unselectedItemColor,
IconThemeData? selectedIconTheme,
IconThemeData? unselectedIconTheme,
double selectedFontSize = 14.0,
double unselectedFontSize = 12.0,
TextStyle? selectedLabelStyle,
TextStyle? unselectedLabelStyle,
bool? showSelectedLabels,
bool? showUnselectedLabels,
MouseCursor? mouseCursor,
bool? enableFeedback,
BottomNavigationBarLandscapeLayout? landscapeLayout}
)
```

[BottomNavigationBar ref](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar/BottomNavigationBar.html)

Comment: thank you for your reply. is there any other widget that does the same functionality? I want.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom Widget with attribute and wrap your Nav Bar.
When adding your bar to a page just make sure to pass your param into the `currentIndex`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomNavBar extends StatelessWidget {

  // The "activePage" should be passed when you create the Widget
  final int activePage;
  
  const BottomNavBar(
    {Key? key,
    required this.activePage
    }): super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(

      // Set the currentIndex to a desired value
      currentIndex: activePage,

      items: const [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: 'Home'
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          label: 'Profile'
        ),
      ],
      onTap: (int idx) {
        ...
      }
    );
  }
}
```

And then when calling the widget use this one:

```
bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavBar(activePage: 0),
```